# Coordinate-free expression of a rotation

Tags: euclidean-geometry, physics, affine-geometry

I'm interested in coordinate free (non-matrix based) approaches to geometry.  What I'd like to do is to show that every Galilean transformation can be written uniquely as the composition of a rotation, a translation, and a uniform motion.

Here's where I'm stuck.  It's easy enough to write down formulas for translation and uniform motion: $$T(t,\mathbf p) = (t + s,\mathbf p + \vec{\mathbf a}) \\ UM(t,\mathbf p) = (t,\mathbf p + t\vec{\mathbf v})$$ but I can't think of a way to describe a given rotation except with matrices.

Question: What's a coordinate-free way (ideally a formula like those above) of specifying a given rotation in $\Bbb R \times \Bbb E^3$?

Comment: $R(p) \cdot R(q) = p \cdot q$

Comment: The dot product on coordinate vectors is clear to me.  But what does it mean to take the dot product of two points in an affine Euclidean space?

Comment: You can define an inner product without coordinate vectors. It would be a bilinear, symmetric, positive-definite mapping... I'm not completely sure I understand your notation, so I can't be more specific just yet. Is $t$ time? If so, why isn't the second transformation $UM(t,p) = (t+s, p+s\vec{v})$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Pt}{\mathbf{p}}$Additon and (real) scalar multiplication don't effect non-trivial rotation, so you can't express a rotation in a form completely analogous to your formulas for translation and uniform motion.

One approach is to introduce a quarter-turn rotation $J$ (which is "secretely" complex multiplication by $i$). Counterclockwise rotation by $\theta$ about the point $\Pt_{0}$ can then be expressed as
$$
R_{\Pt_{0}}(\theta, \Pt) = \Pt_{0} + (\cos\theta)(\Pt - \Pt_{0}) + (\sin\theta) J(\Pt - \Pt_{0}).
$$